# how to use httpd user to run tomcat6 on redhat6?

Tags: java, php, apache, tomcat

1. on redhat6 I installed httpd2.2 & tomcat6.
2. the httpd's user is "apache".
3. the tomcat6's user is "tomcat".
4. now I want use "apache" run both httpd & tomcat.
5. how to config tomcat ?

Why I ask this:
1. now I have a legacy system, php on front and java on background.
2. the system have a config import function.
3. when I upload config file on php UI, the php will great a tmp file in /tmp/***
4. but the java can not read the tmp file, because the tomcat user is "tomcat" and the httpd user is "apache".

so I want to run tomcat as "apache"

Answer (score 0):

You need to install mod_jk to connect Apache and Tomcat.

You can download mod_jk from [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/download-connectors.cgi). You have to choose appropriate version.

Explanation and install guide is shown [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-3.3-doc/mod_jk-howto.html).

Comment: thanks! 

but by this case, I do not want use mod_jk (because the legacy system not use mod_jk or other).

In this case, system use http://localhost:80/upload.php to upload config file, 
and the php source will access http://localhost:8080/api?import_func to import config file to system.

so the legacy system not use mod_jk or other.